Matthew 5:34-37 and Revelation 10:6
So in Matthew, it is written that we are not to swear AT ALL. Anything beyond “Yes” or “No” is evil.
Why then did the Angel in Revelation swear an oath by God?
Paul’s swearing of oath could be an understandable sin. He’s not perfect.
I also understand that angels aren’t perfect. But the Angel in Revelation 6 has been “backed by God” since after he spoke, God spoke. God didn’t condemn the oath.
Some people say that Jesus only refers to false oaths. But it is written that do not make an oath at all.

hi unk unk, welcome to the site. for ὅλως there like totally aren't enough instances to say what it means as restrictively as that. Arndt&Gingrich's first entry is "generally speaking" - Strongs lacks the Hellenistic poets and only has 4 occurrences. The second part about Yes or No where does that come from?

Hello. Forgive me, I didn’t quite catch your statement on “Ardnt&Gingrich’s…occurences”

However, your first statement of it being not “as restrictively as that” is false in my view. Jesus at the very last verse said “Anything more of this (Yes or No) comes from the evil one”. Now the “Yes and No” is from Matthew 5:34-37.

'@unk unk' the word the translations have for 'at all' is ὅλως. In Strongs and phonetically it is something like wholly/completely/totally/by all means/in all ways - but the lexicons have picked up softer usages. Surprisingly, the NT lexicon I checked has "generally speaking" as the first sense for this word, which would take AT ALL out of contention. More like a "by and large, in the main" And if that comes out the reading of Mt.5:34 might need revisiting, or at least it becomes a separate problem. I thought best to check this with you before answering either part of the OP.

The point: Simply tell the truth.
For starters, the Bible contains instances of oaths being used appropriately. God took oaths. Jesus once spoke under oath (Matt. 26:63–64). Paul put himself under oath, calling God as his witness (Rom. 1:9; 2 Cor. 1:23; 1 Thess. 2:10). So, it’s possible that when Jesus said not to swear oaths “at all”, he was speaking hyperbolically to emphasize the importance of honesty.

The worse men are, the less they are bound by oaths; the better they are, the less there is need for them. Our Lord does not enjoin the
precise terms wherein we are to affirm or deny, but such a constant
regard to truth as would render oaths unnecessary. - Matthew Henry's Concise Commentary


God taught the Israelites to guarantee their veracity by swearing,
with God as witness, to tell the truth. He commanded, “You shall not
swear by my name falsely, and so profane the name of your God: I am
the Lord” (Lev. 19:12). Again, “If a man vows a vow to the Lord, . . .
he shall not break his word” (Num. 30:2; cf. Deut. 23:21; 1 Sam. 12:3;
Prov. 29:24). By invoking God as witness, the Israelites called him to
judge and avenge if they failed to perform a vow. So, the law at least
regulates and mitigates the effects of sin. Laws about divorce, oaths,
and property do not describe God’s perfect will; they rein in the
effects of sin. - Crossway

The rabbinic teaching perverted the purpose of oaths:
Jesus was likely addressing the misuse of oaths in his time, where people would swear frivolous or make false oaths.

In Jesus’ day, rabbis concocted a system that defeated the purpose of oaths. They taught that oaths might or might not be binding, depending
on how one swore: If one swore by Jerusalem it was not binding, but if
one swore toward Jerusalem, it was. If one swore by the temple, it was
not binding, but if one swore by the temple’s gold, it was. If one
swore by the altar of sacrifice, it was not binding, if one swore by
the gift on the altar, it was. - Crossway

Bibleref says:

Currently, Jesus is speaking about swearing oaths as a way of
obligating oneself to a task. Someone who said, "I swear to the Lord
to pay you the money" would have to answer to God for their sin if
they did not follow through. However, in practice, Israel's religious leaders allowed for a system of debatable oaths to take hold. Swearing by things and places other than the Lord may have been an attempt to imply less serious consequences for the oath-breaker (Numbers 30:2). They may have also tolerated those who claimed that God, not the oath-maker, was to blame if the promise was not kept.

The purpose of Jesus' teaching:
Jesus' teaching is a call for truthfulness and integrity in all our communications. The idea is that if we are always truthful, we won’t need to swear oaths to guarantee our honesty.

The main reason is that a person known for integrity doesn't need to
enhance their promises. The upright truth behind a Christian's "yes"
and "no" should be strong enough to stand on its own.

On the other hand, in Revelation 10:6, an angel swears an oath by God. This was a solemn declaration of God’s purposes.

And sware by him that liveth for ever and ever That is, by the living
God, who is the true God: and is so described to distinguish him from
idol gods, who have no life nor breath in them; and to assert the
excellency and perfection of his nature, who has life in himself
originally, and independently, is the fountain of life to all
creatures living, and who are supported in their life and being by
him; and so he always was, is, and ever will be; this is the same as
swearing by Ancuialus. (Gill's Exposition of the Bible)

The angel’s oath is clearly not a casual or frivolous one, but a serious declaration made with cosmic significance.
As Christians, whether we’re making a casual statement or a solemn declaration, we should always strive to speak the truth. This is a principle that applies to all of us, whether humans or angels.

Hello. While your explanation is great, it goes against the Word.

The reason for this is Jesus said to only say “Yes and No” and he continued to say that “Anything more of it comes from the evil one”. It’s true that the Rabbis during that time had falsified the use of oath and it is well documented in the Word in Matthew 23. However, when Jesus came, He removed the taking oaths all together. It is even written in James. Even if the Angel is declaring the glory of God and He is, it is still a violation of the Law of Christ. Yet, in the next verses, God didn’t really go against the Angel’s words

@unkunk Literalists, such as the first Anabaptists, took no vows. As a result, they couldn't hold military or civic positions. Yet, Jesus spoke under oath and God took vows for those who did not know his reliability. The disciples would take oaths to assure those who do not know them. For similar reasons, Paul put himself under oath, calling God as his witness (Rom. 1:9; 2 Cor. 1:23; 1 Thess. 2:10).

Answer
The angel in Revelation 10:6 didn’t violate Jesus’s command in Matthew 5:34-37.
Explanation
Let us see what Jesus said in Mat 5:34-37:

“But I say to you, Do not swear at all, neither by Heaven, because
it is God's throne; nor by the earth, because it is the footstool
of His feet; nor by Jerusalem, because it is the city of the great
King. Nor shall you swear by your head, because you are not able
to make one hair white or black. But let your word be Yes, yes; No,
no. For the excess of these is from evil”.

So, yes, Jesus said not to swear at all 1) by Heaven, 2) by the earth, 3) by Jerusalem, and 4) by your head.
And the angel in Revelation didn’t swear by any of these four things!
Background
The fact is, Jesus was correcting His disciples and followers from the wrong influence of the Pharisees, Sadducees and Scribes.

“And Jesus said to them, Watch and take heed from the leaven of the
Pharisees and Sadducees.” (Mat 16:6). “Then they knew that He did not
say to take heed from the leaven of bread, but from the doctrine of
the Pharisees and Sadducees” (verse 12).

These Pharisees and others had the habit of swearing falsely by various holy things in Jesus’ day:

“Woe to you, blind guides, who say, Whoever swears by the Holy Place,
it is nothing; but whoever swears by the gold of the Holy Place is a
debtor. Fools and blind! For which is greater, the gold, or the Holy
Place that sanctifies the gold?............ And the one swearing by
the Holy Place swears by it, and by the One dwelling in it. And the
one swearing by Heaven swears by the throne of God, and by the One
sitting on it. Woe to you, scribes and Pharisees, hypocrites!” (Mat
23:16-17, 21-23).

So, it is obvious that Jesus was speaking against such false and dishonest swearing.
the Principle
The principle to be followed by a conscientious Christian follower is to be careful with his words. King Solomon has given the principle so beautifully here:

“When you vow a vow to God, do not delay paying it, for he has no
pleasure in fools. Pay what you vow. It is better that you should
not vow than that you should vow and not pay” (Eccl 5:4-5).

This is why Jesus said to limit our promises/vows/swearing to yes and no. More than these can trap us in our own words.
Conclusion
So, the angel in Revelation did not violate Jesus’ words in Matthew 5:34-37.

I don't think that "Not at all" does not primarily refer to an oath taken in a court of law, but to the common practice of taking an oath in the course of everyday speech as a "guarantee" of one's reliability. Compare this to Matthew 23:16-22.
Jesus commanded His followers not to make an oath of any kind, because a disciple must be dependable enough that his word alone is adequate, Matthew 5:37, "But let your statement be, "Yes, yes, or No, no; and anything beyond these is of evil."
The passage is not concerned with the taking an oath per se, but with the unconditional integrity of the disciple. Moreover, elsewhere, the Scriptures declare that God swears by Himself (Genesis 22:16; Psalm 110:4; Isaiah 45:23).
In the New Testament we have Hebrews 6:13, "For when God made the promise to Abraham, since He could swear by no one greater, He swore by Himself, vs14, saying, I will surely bless you, and I will surely multiply you." What's interesting about this verse is the fact that it is referring back to Genesis 22:16 where the angel of the Lord said, "By Myself I have sworn declares the Lord, because you have done this thing, and have not withheld your son, your only son,"
Jesus also did not forbid taking an oath at His own trial. The high priest Caiaphas ask Jesus to swear as to His identity. Matthew 26:63,"But Jesus kept silent. And the high priest said to Him, "I adjure You by the living God, that You tell us whether You are the Christ, the Son of God." At Luke 22:70 Jesus responded, "Yes, I am."
Matthew 26:65, "Then the high priest tore his robes, saying, He has blasphemed! It is clear, at least from Matthew 5:35-37 that every oath involves God whether the name of God is used in it or not. Swearing by one's head implies one has powers he does not possess. he does not have control over it, for he cannot by the most concentrated mental effort make one hair change color. Furthermore, to swear by one's head or in other words one's life, over which only God has power, is indirectly swearing by God.
In short, Jesus desires all His followers be reliable and trustworthy. Their "yes" is to mean "yes," and their "no" is to mean "no." Regarding the angel at Revelation 10:6, notice he "swore by Him who lives for ever and ever who created heaven and the things in it, and the earth and the things in it, and the sea and the things in it, and there shall be delay no longer."

Now this view is really interesting for me. The view or interpretation of not using an oath for an everyday use. Unfortunately, we can’t tie it to a proof. The examples you have provided from the OT is also not applicable. Since Paul said that Christ has been the end of the Law. It is also written that we are no longer under the Law but Grace of God (which comes from Jesus’ death). Now since we’re not under the Law, the OT’s example of taking your oath truthfully cannot really apply. I mean the OT says we can’t eat swine. Jesus said we can. Whom do we follow?

So if we take a close look, we only look at the examples in the NT. But the examples are Paul swearing by God in Galatians. Aswell as the Angel swearing by God. Even though they proclaim God’s greatness and the prophesies, they still violated the Law of Christ.
